# how to search nsmutable array in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can any body tell me how to search NSMutable Arry in which objects are stored from xml feed
i have the following code

```
- (void) searchTableView {

NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//blog entries is the nsmutable array in which objects are stored from RSS feed
for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in blogEntries)
{ 
    NSArray *images=[dictionary objectForKey:@"image"];
    NSArray *titlearray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSDictionary *imagesDic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:images forKey:@"image"];
    NSDictionary *titlearrayDic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:titlearray forKey:@"title"];
    [searchArray addObject:imagesDic];
    [searchArray addObject:titlearrayDic];
}
//know the problem comes in below code i just want to compare title not image string as there any way to search only of title array not for both image in title some what like this For(nsstring *stemp in searcArray.titleArray etc)
for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
{
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length > 0){

            [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];

    }}
```

the problem is that this code just saving title not image and if i save image then it also search in image string which i dont want to do. i want the user will search only by title then when he type something in textbox if search is true against some values then only thos e are displayed in table cell with title and image.
as this is RSS APPLiction and feeds are comming from xml feed
which 
[click here](http://www.luxury.net/feed/rss/celebrity.xml)
bescially i am extracting this xml feed and em displaying image and title tage in table cell know i want to implement searchbar in it
Thanks....**i am waiting for your response...**

Comment: Can you give an example of the array?

Comment: What do you mean by "search"? Do you need to filter the array down to those meeting certain criteria? Do you need just the first that meets the criteria? You need to clarify before you can expect any meaningful answers.

Answer (score 2):

@mipadi is right - try using `containsObject:` first.

If that doesn't work, just a simple loop will do it - you can put in whatever matching criteria you want in there. e.g. This code searches by comparing the name properties :

```
- (id)searchArray:(NSArray *)haystack for:(id)needle {
    for(id temp in haystack)
        if ([temp name] isEqual:[needle name]])
            return needle;

    return nil;
}
```

Hope that helps.

NB If you're using your own objects in the array, you can use `containsObject:` if you have overridden [`isEqual:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCCECDG) (and `hash`)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want to search. If you're just looking for a particular object, you can use [`containsObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about what you want, it's tough to answer your question. But here are some starting points:

1. [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray) - Check out the methods starting like `indexOfObject-`; I think one of these probably does what you want. There's also `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`.
2. [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003688) - The only notable method here is `filterUsingPredicate`, I think.

Hope one of these helps you.